# Using java library in PHP

Tags: java, php

There is a java library which I would like to use in my php code. The library contains many functions that I need for my program and convert the library to php would take a lot of time.

Is there anyway I can use the library as is in my code? So if for example I have a class name which is "Test" and a function which is getText() could I do something like

test = new Test();

echo test.getText();

If such a thing or something similar does exist, I would like to know about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (See also ["use java from php"](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+java+from+php))

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out! Funny thing is when I ran a search I couldn't find it :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is few links that will helps you.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/java.examples.php

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/examples.php